# How to download complete webpage using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have to write a Python code that will get URL, open a Chrome/Firefox browser using Selenium and will download it as a "Complete Webpage", mean with the CSS assets for example.

I know the basis of using Selenium, like:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ff = webdriver.firefox()
ff.get(URL)

ff.close
```

How can I perform the downloading action (Like clicking automatically in the browser CTRL+S)?

Comment: Found an answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729201/save-complete-web-page-incl-css-images-using-python-selenium

Answer (score -1):

You can try following code to get `HTML` page as file:

```
from selenium import webdriver

ff = webdriver.Firefox()
ff.get(URL)
with open('/path/to/file.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(ff.page_source)
ff.close
```

Comment: this one saves just the source code whereas i need the whole page

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what you get if you use `CTRL+S`. And what do you mean "whole page"?

Comment: when you clicking CTRL+S you get the whole page, mean that it will include the Page's CSS for example. While downloading the page source you will get just the source code as a text (The relative CSS won't be downloaded)

Comment: With `CTRL+S` you can download `HTML` (source code) only! `.css`, `.js` files are not part of "whole page", but separate files that browser should request from server while `.html` file parsing and page rendering

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer but I'm 100% sure that when you click on `CTRL+S` you have an option named "complete web page" that will download the CSS files too. (I just did it manually right now and want to perform this by automated script)

Comment: Oh, yeap, sorry, now I see that option :) Initially, I thought you want to get the whole page as a single file... now it make sense.